# Django/Python DRY: how to avoid repeat code when working with Q objects and model attributes

Tags: python, django, dry, django-q

I'm trying to build a search page that will allow a user to find any instances of a model which meet certain threshold criteria and am having trouble avoiding seriously redundant code. I'm hoping there's a better way to do it. Here's a slightly contrived example that should illustrate what I'm trying to do, with the relevant code adjusted at the end. The user will interact with the search with checkboxes.

models.py:

```
class Icecream(models.Model()):
    name = models.CharField()
    bad_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    okay_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    tasty_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    delicious_threshold = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py:

```
def search_icecreams(request):
    user = request.user
    q_search = None

    if 'taste_search' in request.GET: 
        q_search = taste_threshold_set(request, user, q_search)

    if q_search == None:
        icecream_list = Icecream.objects.order_by('name')
    else:
        icecream_list = College.objects.filter(q_search)

    context = { 'icecream_list' : icecream_list }
    return render(request, '/icecream/icecreamsearch.html', context)
```

The relevant code that I want to cut down is as follows, this is pretty much straight from my project, with the names changed.

```
def taste_threshold_set(request, user, q_search):
    threshold = request.GET.getlist('taste_search')
    user_type_tolerance = user.profile.get_tolerance_of(icea

    # 1-5 are the various thresholds. They are abbreviated to cut down on the
    # length of the url.
    if '1' in threshold:
        new_q = Q(bad_threshold__gt = user.profile.taste_tolerance)        

        if q_search == None:
            q_search = new_q
        else:
            q_search = (q_search) | (new_q)

    if '2' in threshold:
        new_q = Q(bad_threshold__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance) & \
            ~Q(okay_threshold__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance)

        if q_search == None:
            q_search = new_q
        else:
            q_search = (q_search) | (new_q)

    if '3' in threshold:
        new_q = Q(okay_threshold_3__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance) & \
            ~Q(tasty_threshold__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance)

        if q_search == None:
            q_search = new_q
        else:
            q_search = (q_search) | (new_q)

    if '4' in threshold:
        new_q = Q(tasty_threshold__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance) & \
            ~Q(delicious_threshold__lte=user.profile.taste_tolerance)

        if q_search == None:
            q_search = new_q
        else:
            q_search = (q_search) | (new_q)

    if '5' in threshold:
        new_q = Q(delicious_threshold__lte = user.profile.taste_tolerance)        

        if q_search == None:
            q_search = new_q
        else:
            q_search = (q_search) | (new_q)

    return q_search
```

Basically I want the user to be able to find all instances of a certain object which meet a given threshold level. So, for example, all icecreams that they would find bad and all icecreams that they would find delicious.

There are a number of things I'm not happy with about this code. I don't like checking to see if the Q object hasn't been instantiated yet for each possible threshold, but don't see a way around it. Further, if this were a non-django problem I'd use a loop to check each of the given thresholds, instead of writing each one out. But again, I'm not sure how to do that.

Finally, the biggest problem is, I need to check thresholds for probably 20 different attributes of the model. As it stands, I'd have to write a new threshold checker for each one, each only slightly different than the other (the name of the attribute they're checking). I'd love to be able to write a generic checker, then pass it the specific attribute. Is there any way to solve this, or my other two problems?

Thanks!

Comment: is this code working ? `(q_search)` looks invalid unless the parameter `q_search` is a `Q` object

Comment: Are you talking about the third code block? It's slightly modified from my code (which is working), so I might've broke something, but I think it works. The q_search parameter will either be None or a Q object, but it always checks to see if it is None. If it is, it names the new_q q_search and moves on, if it isn't it ors the old and the new, saving the result. Well, that's the goal, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
query_arg = ['bad_threshold__lte', 'bad_threshold__lte', 'okay_threshold_3__lte', 'tasty_threshold__lte', 'delicious_threshold__lte']

Q(**{query_arg[int(threshold) - 1]: user.profile.taste_tolerance})
```

Comment: Very nice! This is pretty close to exactly what I was looking for. I'm guessing I should be able to pass in the `user.profile.taste_tolerance` section as well, which should allow for it to be generalized amongst all attributes. So I guess this means `attribute_name__lte` is a keyword parameter for all Q objects and query sets? That's very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use own `QuerySet` for the models instead `def taste_threshold_set(...)`

Example:

> ```
> models.py:
> ...
> from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
> ...
>
> class IcecreamManager(models.Manager):
>
>     def get_query_set(self):
>         return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
>
>     def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
>         try:
>             return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
>         except AttributeError:
>             return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)
>
>
> class Icecream(models.Model()):
>     name = models.CharField()
>     bad_threshold = models.IntegerField()
>     okay_threshold = models.IntegerField()
>     tasty_threshold = models.IntegerField()
>     delicious_threshold = models.IntegerField()
>
>     objects = IcecreamManager()
>
>     class QuerySet(QuerySet):
>         def name_custom_method(self, arg1, argN):
>             # you must rewrite for you solution
>             return self.exclude(
>                             time_end__gt=now()
>                         ).filter(
>                             Q(...) | Q(...)
>                         )
>
>         def name_custom_method2(...)
>             ...
> ```

These should give you abilities build of chains querys for your issues.

Comment: Thanks @Abbasov, that probably is a better place to put the logic, instead of in the view. Though I'm a little confused how to then interact with the custom QuerySet. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It simple as usual in Django `Icecream.objects.name_custom_method2(...).name_custom_method(...).filter(...)` or `Icecream.objects.filter(...).name_custom_method2(...).name_custom_method(...)` In other words, you will can does an any chains from Django's and own QuerySet's functions for search the result

Comment: Wouldn't I have to define a custom manager to do it this way? As it stands I get the error `AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'custom_method'`

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot initial `IcecreamManager`. I updated code above

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It, combined with Wonil's answer, provides a very elegant solution to all three of my problems. I'd throw you a +1 if I could.